# Prove the logarithm property $\ln(\frac 1a) = -\ln(a)$ using its definition of fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC).

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, substitution, change-of-variable

I know how to prove that. But I have a question about variable substitution.

**Problem statement:**
Prove directly from the definition $ L(x) = \int_{1}^x  \frac 1tdt $ that $L\left(\frac 1a\right) = -L(a)$, by making a change of variables in the definite integral.

**Proof**:

$$L\left(\frac 1a\right) = \int_{1}^{\frac 1a}  \frac 1tdt \tag1$$
Substitute: $$\frac 1t = u \to t = \frac 1u\tag2$$ and $$dt = \frac {-1}{u^2}\tag{2'}$$
$$L\left(\frac 1a\right) = \int_{1}^{\frac 1a}  \frac 1tdt=\int_{1}^{a}  -\frac {\frac 1u^2}{\frac 1u}du =-\int_{1}^{a}  \frac {1}{u}du \tag3$$
$$-\int_{1}^{a}  \frac {1}{u}du = -\ln(a) - \ln(1) = -\ln(a) = -L(a)\tag4$$

**The question is:** Why do we change $\frac 1a \to a$ in the third step?
Thank you.

Comment: Technically, the last line should be $-\ln(a)-(-\ln 1).$ Doesn’t matter because $\ln(1)=0.$ But you really shouldn’t be using $\ln$ here when this value, by definition, is $-L(a).$ The whole point of using $L$ is we want to show $L$ has the property of a logarithm, which is made moot if you assume $L(a)=\ln a.$

Comment: As to your question, in general, if we do the substitution $t=f(u)$ we can’t assume $u$ will be integrated over the same range. Rather: $$\int_{b}^c g(t)\,dt=\int_{f^{-1}(b)}^{f^{-1}(c)} g(f(u))f’(u)\,du$$ In your case, $f(u)=1/u$ so $f^{-1}(t)=1/t.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you for your explanations and corrections. It helped me to understand better the change of variables.